# What is difference between session and cookie in php?

Tags: php

Hi I would like to know the difference between a `php session` and a `cookie`

Comment: @BoltClock yeah, we definitely need to see more of that cynical condescending tone on innocent beginners to really boost your low self esteem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Sessions and Cookies in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339783/what-is-the-difference-between-sessions-and-cookies-in-php)

Comment: @ cookie vs session http://www.codingslover.com/2015/04/difference-between-cookies-and-sessions.html

Answer (score 26):

The main difference being that session data is stored on the server, while cookie data is stored on the client. Therefore, a client can easily modify the cookie contents, but will have to work way harder to modify the session contents.

Comment: Something else to not about this topic: Session handling by server almost always rely on cookies. A session cookie is passed over and over between the server and the client.

Answer (score 15):

Cookies are a means to store information in the end-user's browser, so that the server can track the end-user.

Sessions are also implemented by using cookies, but the actual data is not in the browser; rather, it is stored in the user's session record on the server. In the case of sessions, cookies are used to identify a particular end-user's session identifier on the server records. Hence, they are a more secure way of storing user information.

Answer (score 8):

A cookie is a ~piece of data stored on the client side.
Data stored in session is stored on the server side, and the various sessions are identified by cookies.

Answer (score 6):

There are session and Cookies, both are used to store values or data.  But there are some key differences between session and cookie: a cookie stores the data in your browser and a session is stored on the server. Cookie data is available in your browser up to expiration date and session data available for the browser run, after closing the browser we will lose the session information.

Comment: It is important to note that an id that points to the session data is stored in a cookie on the computer.

Answer (score 5):

A cookie is often used to identify a user. A cookie is a small file that the server embeds on the user's computer. Each time the same computer requests a page with a browser, it will send the cookie too.

A session variable is used to store information about, or change settings for a user session. Session variables hold information about one single user, and are available to all pages in one application.

Comment: You need to call session_start to make the data available though.

Comment: -1 because this doesn't actually say anything about the differences. From your description, session variables could just as well be stored in cookies (which they are not).

Answer (score 3):

A cookie is an unique information that the user sends to the web server with each request in order to identify him. This unique id could be used to store information about this specific user on the server (session).

Answer (score 1):

Cookies will only expire on expiry time or if you explicitly clean cookie / cache of your browser. Cookies will retain into the system even after you open your browser next day.
Cookies are stored on client's system so they are less secure.

Session will expire on its expiry time or if the browser has been closed. As session is stored on server so it is more secure.

So for a login module, a combination of session and cookie should be used

Answer (score 0):

Cookies stored client side but session stored server side.

cookies is without sign out of the your email account and close it. once again can not enter username and password but your email account is open.

session is close the webpage once again open to starting page appier

Comment: -1 because this is uncomprehensible. You will need to clarify a lot of your answer. For example, what does this mean: `cookies is without sign out of the your email account and close it`?

Answer (score 0):

best example to illustrate the difference bet. Session and Cookies is:-
when you Login as a member in any Site it Creates Sessions until you log out...
that is Session..

and Cookies when you browse websites the are stored on your computer's Main Memory that is Cookies

i-e Session is Server side
and cookies is Client side

Comment: you know the difference in location of each one, but your example is not good

Answer (score 0):

We got three differences in general. The key difference would be cookies are stored in client side and sessions are stored in server side. The second difference would be cookies can only store strings. We can store our objects in sessions. Storing objects in sessions were really useful according to my experience. Another difference was that we could be save cookie for future reference, but session couldn’t. When users close their browser, they also lost the session.

Comment: -1: The session may not be lost after closing the browser, see `session.cookie_lifetime` and `session.gc_maxlifetime` settings in php.ini. Objects are stored in sessions in serialized (i.e. text) form [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) and the same technique can be used for cookies.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Sessions

PHP has built-in functions to save session variables. The variables are stored in state files. These state files need not be explicitly created and managed. The following are the steps for saving and retrieving values of session variables.

The setcookie() command must be issued before any printed output occurs because the cookie must be written as part of the HTTP header. PHP automatically parses any HTTP_COOKIE string into an associative array $_COOKIE. The value of the cookie can be retrieved from the cookie thus:

$_COOKIE["some_var"]

Answer (score 0):

Cookie: A key/value pair that is stored by the user's browser and is available in the superglobal $_COOKIE array available in PHP. The cookie request is initiated with an explicitly defined expiration date. For example:

setcookie('cookieName', $some_value, time()+3600, "/", ".example.com")

On the next server request, $_COOKIE['cookieName'] will be available. If you use a browser tool to look at the cookie, it will have an expiration date.

Session Cookie: Identical to the above but defined without an expiration date. If you use the same browser tool it will say that the cookie expires at the end of the session; which is ultimately when you close your browser. For example:

setcookie('cookieName', $some_value);

PHP Session: a server side mechanism that will associate a bunch of data with a session id. Every time a session is invoked, it serializes/unserializes it. This could be more data than just a single key/value pair that a cookie supports, but the way of associating this data with a user is by creating a cookie (regular or session as described above) in their browser that contains the session id. This way, the right data can be retrieved for a given user based on the value of that cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Both are super global, i.e, they can be used anywhere in the site.

Differences between sessions and cookies:

- Cookies are stored in the browser (client side) while sessions are stored in the server (host).
- Cookies are remembered till they are deleted while sessions are deleted when the user closes the tab/browser (depending on the browser).
- Cookies can be seen by the user while sessions cannot.

Due to the reasons above, I would recommend to not store sensitive data in cookies and store the data that is to be remembered even after the user has left in cookies.

Answer (score -1):

Cookie - Stored data in browser and will work on browser related and client side only...For example if you are trying to log in gmail account with username and password,After entered login successful if you close the current tab and after sometime opening same page the login page won't come it will open directly with login details..This is cookie..

Session - Stored data in server side for example same as cookie example after entered login details you will get notification as successful once you close the browser then open after some time it will ask again login details(more example shopping also)