# Laravel5 AJAX set cookie not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cookies, laravel-5

Could you give me advice please?

I'm saving in COOKIES some data. I create method for this in Laravel, so I call ajax on this method to set cookie but when I try to call next request where I access this cookie value, it is not saved and I can access it in second request... I don't know why... it's quite strange :/

I have this code:

```
public function setCookie: method in laravel controller to set cookie
var setCookie: function in javascript where I call ajax request to set cookie
var loadEvents: method called after ajax call where I set cookie.


public function setCookie(Request $request) {

    $cookieName = $request->input('cookie_name');
    $cookieVal = $request->input('cookie_val');

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success'])->withCookie(cookie($cookieName, $cookieVal));
}


var setCookie = function (cookieName, cookieVal) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: window.setCookieUrl,
        data: {
            cookie_name: cookieName,
            cookie_val: cookieVal,
            _token: getCsrfToken()
        }
    }).done();
};



public function loadEvents(Request $request) {

    $activeCalendarsIds = $request->input('active_calendars_ids');
    if($activeCalendarsIds == null)
        $activeCalendarsIds = Cookie::get('adminActiveCalendars');


    $eventsPage = $this->getPostParam('page');
    $eventsLimit = $this->getPostParam('limit');

    $this->service->setFilter('page', $eventsPage);
    $this->service->setFilter('limit', $eventsLimit);

    $events = $this->service->getCalendarsEvents($activeCalendarsIds);
    $eventList = view('admin/calendar/event_list', ['events' => $events]);

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'data' => '' . $eventList . ''
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX call that sets the cookie has finished before the call that uses the cookie?

Comment: And if the cookie-setting method is just what you posted, you could just set the cookie from Javascript

Comment: Yes, it is finished, because I check AJAX call response.
Problem is, that JavaScript setting of cookies is complicated to work with Laravel5, because laravel set cookies na database.

Comment: How about $activeCalendarsIds = $request->cookie('adminActiveCalendars');

Comment: Nope :/ This doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** the following works as expected. It seems there's a mixup in the order the requests are stated. The setCookie ajax request must be finished before any loadEvent ajax request is sent.

**Controller actions:**

```
public function set(Request $request)
{
    $cookieName = $request->input('cookie_name');
    $cookieVal = $request->input('cookie_val');
    return response()->json(['previousCookieValue' => Cookie::get('adminActiveCalendars')])->withCookie(cookie($cookieName, $cookieVal));
}

public function events() {
    return response()->json([
        'cookieValue' => Cookie::get('adminActiveCalendars'),
    ]);
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
var setCookie = function(cookieName, cookieVal) {
  console.log('Set cookie', cookieName, cookieVal);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{{ route('cookies.set') }}',
    data: {
      cookie_name: cookieName,
      cookie_val: cookieVal,
      _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log('Response:', response);
    }
  });
};

var loadEvents = function() {
  console.log('Load events');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '{{ route('cookies.events') }}',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log('Response:', response);
    }
  });
};
```

**Template:**

```
<button onclick="loadEvents();" type="button">Load Events</button>
<button onclick="setCookie('adminActiveCalendars', 'Foo');" type="button">Set Cookie Foo</button>
<button onclick="setCookie('adminActiveCalendars', 'Bar');" type="button">Set Cookie Bar</button>
```

**Console output:**

```
Load events
Object {cookieValue: null} // initially empty
Set cookie adminActiveCalendars Foo
Response: Object {previousCookieValue: null}
Load events
Response: Object {cookieValue: "Foo"} // first loadEvents request after setting cookie already holds correct value
Set cookie adminActiveCalendars Bar
Response: Object {previousCookieValue: "Foo"}
Load events
Response: Object {cookieValue: "Bar"}
```

After fully reloading the page, then loading events:

```
Load events
Response: Object {cookieValue: "Bar"} // still here, right from the start
```

---

**Notes on alternative approaches:**

- Without knowing the internals of the application - it seems setting the cookie on the client side would be sufficient
- Alternatively, store this kind of information in a Session variable rather than in a Cookie if it's not needed for something else on the client side. [There are some differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339783/what-is-the-difference-between-sessions-and-cookies-in-php). First of all you would not have to bother handling cookies on both sides (client and server).
- Alternatively, do not store this information anywhere - add it to the request as filter parameters.

---

***Original answer:***

This doesn't set a cookie:

```
return view('welcome')->withCookie(cookie($cookieName, $cookieVal, 45000));
```

This does:

```
$response = new \Illuminate\Http\Response('Test');
$response->withCookie(cookie($cookieName, $cookieVal, 45000));
return $response;
```

Adaption of:

- https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#cookies
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-set-a-cookie-with-laravel-5

Comment: I use it in view then and I think it's better. Anyway, I think that laravel doesn't make difference between cookies and sessions, both is stored in database or files, not?

Comment: Anyway the code you provide work still as mine -> i make request, it probably set but in next ajax call it is not updated and I have to make next one ajax call to see new value :/

Comment: Thank you very much @luchaos! It works. I just need to call next ajax call after cookie was set :/ Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, @JanKožušník! Glad I could help and it's working now.