# Adding a class to Body in PHP and keeping it with a session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, session

I've been trying to figure this out on my own, but I can't seem to get it sorted.

I'm building an accessibility section on a client site, and i've got two buttons, the buttons add a class to the body, one is `font-size` the other is `greyscale`.

I need these classes to stay on the body until clicked again to remove, as users don't want to have to keep clicking the buttons to be able to see the site.

I want to store these classes with a session or cookie, but having done some reading, sessions store cookies anyway, so whichever is the best option.

I'm using **wordpress** for the site, so if there's something I can use function wise, that'd be useful to know!

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use localStorage you can use this code.

```
// Check if localStorage is supported
if ('localStorage' in window && typeof localStorage == 'object') {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Set the class if greyscale is set
    // Note that localStorage saves everything as strings
    if (localStorage["greyscale"] == "1") {
      $('body').addClass('greyscale');
    }
    // Register click listener for the button
    $('#button').click(function() {
      // Toggle greyscale on and off
      if (localStorage["greyscale"] != "1") {
        $('body').addClass('greyscale');
        localStorage["greyscale"] = "1";
      }
      else {
        $('body').removeClass('greyscale');
        localStorage["greyscale"] = "0";
      }
    }); // - button click
  }); // - doc ready
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MsrU/2/)

Comment: Do you recommend a fallback dude? Though, having checked [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=sessionstorage) it seems pretty well supported enough to not need one...

Comment: You can make a fallback if you wish. It depends how doggedly you want to provide support. I would not recommend it because I consider it to be a lot of work to satisfy a very small percentage of users (if any at all).

Comment: The purpose of this is for accessibility, It works back down to IE8, but not on Opera, so I'm hoping that charities and people with vision impairment have up to date computers. Elderly People too.

Answer (score 1):

Session is usually using cookies but data is stored on server side and cookie is only used to identify it.

Assuming you have no reason to know if user is using gray scale on server side you can do this entirely in JS.

For example using some neat jQuery plugin for cookies https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
//set cookie and add class on button click
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.cookie('greyscale', true);
    $('body').addClass('greyscale');
});

//check for cookie on document load
$(function(){
    if($.cookie("greyscale")){
        $('body').addClass('greyscale'); 
    }
});
```

Also please have in mind that this cookie will be sent to server and back over and over again so if you don't need this on server side you should use some more modern solution like HTML5 localStorage. There are few libraries that can be used to keep data on client side. They use modern features and fallback to old ones(like cookies) on older browsers. Please check http://pablotron.org/software/persist-js/ for example.

Comment: I'm currently using something similar to this using jQuery.Cookie, however, it seems to have issues with adding and removing the cookies.

How would you remove the cookies on click and make sure that when you refresh it doesn't alter these state?

Comment: Please check documentation for plugin you are using. with this https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie you can do $.removeCookie('greyscale'); to remove cookie. Also check Firefox firebug or chromium developer tools "cookies" tab to test what is actually happening in the browser.

Comment: Yeah i'm deep into that, just getting issues with adding and removing the cookies, $.removeCookie often doesn't like to remove the cookie to remove the class

Comment: If you are having problems you can try simply to set cookie to false instead of deleting it to see where is the problem. $.cookie('greyscale', false);

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478805/what-is-difference-between-session-and-cookie-in-php):

> The main difference being that session data is stored on the server, while cookie data is stored on the client. Therefore, a client can easily modify the cookie contents, but will have to work way harder to modify the session contents.

Comment: Cheers for explaining the difference between these,all that is stored is YES or NO, which will turn the class on or off, so if the user wants to change that themselves, they can go mad

Comment: Exactly ;) Cookies is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to approach this

**1)** Keep the information in $_SESSION.

**2)** Keep the information in cookie.

Based on your case and on the data you want to store (which are not critical), I'd suggest you store it in a cookie and not bother the server to keep track for every user.

You could easily store information in a cookie via javascript.

Here is a *javascript* cookie reference for you:

> http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

After storing your info inside a cookie you could retrieve the info stored inside a cookie via javascript or php.
Keep in mind:
Javascript = client side (server wont be bothered) & after your dom is ready you will have to add the according class to your body.
PHP = server side, meaning that you wont have to add a class after the dom is ready and print your html with the appropriate class already set on the element.

*PHP* cookie references:

> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp
>
> http://davidwalsh.name/php-cookies

Comment: Please don't use w3schools as reference, see http://w3fools.com/ for an explanation, why not to reference to this site in educational material.

Comment: Didn't know of this site and I w3schools helped me when I was starting .I didn't have any trouble back then.

Comment: The example codes on the js_cookies.asp link contain lots of errors. And the code is often bad practice and not even properly formatted. Look at the last example, they use JavaScript in HTML without `<script>` and `</script>` tag,.. it won't event work

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a cookie.

Using cookies you can choose when will the cookie expire, when using sessions - when session is destroyed information is lost eg. when user logs off.

User will have to manually delete your cookie to delete the "body class information"