# How to fade between classes in a conditional query

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to work out how to fade between css classes triggered by a conditional button click. Instead of a simple class on and class off.

I've adapted the below jsfiddle from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017193/adding-a-class-to-body-in-php-and-keeping-it-with-a-session) to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/v5vw9r3a/3/); mostly working, except for the fade.

```js
     // Check if localStorage is supported
    if ('localStorage' in window && typeof localStorage == 'object') {
      $(document).ready(function() {

        // Set the class if greyscale is set
        // Note that localStorage saves everything as strings
        if (localStorage["darkmode"] == "1") {
          $('html').addClass('dark');
          $('.daytime').addClass('nighttime').removeClass('daytime');
          $("#lightson").val("Turn Lights back on");
        }
        // Register click listener for the button
        $('#lightson').click(function() {
          // Toggle greyscale on and off
          if (localStorage["darkmode"] != "1") {
            $('html').addClass('dark').removeClass('light').fadeIn("fast");
            localStorage["darkmode"] = "1";
            $('.daytime').addClass('nighttime').removeClass('daytime');
            $("#lightson").val("Turn Lights back on");
          } else {
            $('html').removeClass('dark').addClass('light').fadeIn("fast");
            localStorage["darkmode"] = "0";
            $('.nighttime').addClass('daytime').removeClass('nighttime');
            $("#lightson").val("Dark Mode");
          }
        }); // - button click
      }); // - doc ready
    }
```

```css
html.light {
  background: white;
  color: grey;
}
html.dark {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus egestas libero lectus, ac elementum est euismod sit amet. Sed maximus ac ipsum non pulvinar. Nulla tempor turpis a metus sollicitudin, in interdum dui mollis. Curabitur dictum magna magna,
  sit amet tempus justo consequat sit amet. Vestibulum varius nisl justo, vel egestas justo scelerisque sit amet. Duis vulputate lacinia lacus id lacinia. Sed vel tellus id nulla finibus pellentesque vel eu sapien. Praesent risus eros, pellentesque in
  tempor a, vestibulum sit amet purus. Mauris sapien velit, varius nec ex eget, vestibulum laoreet diam. Nam eros nisi, euismod ultrices viverra eu, dictum quis nisl. Suspendisse quis eleifend quam. Curabitur consectetur diam non ante rutrum, tincidunt
  placerat felis tincidunt. Fusce vitae dolor dui. Morbi mattis eu dui sit amet laoreet.</div>
<input type="button" id="lightson" class="daytime" value="Dark Mode">
```

You can see the transition is harsh between dark to light and I would like to fade between them some how. I tried appending: `.fadeIn("fast");` to the two 'add and removeClass' lines in the above jsfiddle statements like this: `$('html').addClass('dark').removeClass('light').fadeIn("fast");`

However that seemed to not do anything at all, and probably for a good reason

I cannot solve the issue with plain css in the stylesheet as I don't want the fade in effect each time the page loads, just when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'fadeIn' method in jQuery animates the opacity of a hidden element rather than animating between classes.

Have you considered using css transitions?

```
html {
    background:white;
    color:grey;
    transition: all 0.4s
}
html.dark {
    background: grey;
    color: white;
}
```

Then the only javascript you need is to toggle the 'dark' class on the html element.

The reason you get the fade in when you load the page, is in your original code you are applying the 'dark' class after the page has loaded, which triggers the animation.  If you ensure that the HTML tag doesn't have the 'transition' property until after you've set your initial styles you can avoid this unwanted animation.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/mnqzps8L/2/) using your original code.  Note the extra line:

```
document.createElement('div').offsetHeight;
```

This is needed because some browsers won't apply style changes immediately as they try and optimise the number of times they redraw the layout by queueing changes until they have to. This hack forces the browser to apply your styles immediately as it has to make sure it's giving you the correct value.

Comment: Thank you Jordan, this is an excellent solution. However as mentioned this creates a fade in effect every time the page is loaded.

Comment: How about adding the transition property to a separate class, that's only added after you initially apply your light or dark class.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/mnqzps8L/2/

Comment: Jordan this last one is an innovative solution that I would like to make the answer! How do I do that? Is it possible for you to edit your answer and include it up there? Thanks very much for contributing. You have saved me a day or a week. Anyway I don't quite understand it, however it seems to do everything needed without the need for the weighty jQuery UI library that the excellent solutions above require.

Comment: I've modified my original answer, and hopefully given a bit more explanation.  Glad to help !

Comment: Thanks for the explaination Jordan. This has done the trick! Which is what counts. And it doesn't require the extra page weight of the UI library, which I mentioned above. Thanks again for some out of the box thinking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery-ui and the `.switchClass()` function

```
$('html').switchClass('light','dark', 1000, 'linear');
```

and to change back

```
$('html').switchClass('dark','light', 1000, 'linear');
```

[.switchClass() Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/)

Alternatively you can use the `.toggleClass()` and give the body the default light properties, this would be easy for toggling.

[.toggleClass() Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/)

You can also use the jquery `.animate()` function, you would need to specify the css within the  function however not the class names.

[.animate() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Thanks very much, this is very helpful. I'm going to look in to the switchClass.

Answer (score 1):

Since this was downvote-worthy, I'll elaborate.

---

You can't fade in or out a class. Either you have it, or you don't. What you can do is to transition the styles associated with that class. However, the fadeIn / fadeOut functions are not the way to do that:

> The fadeIn() method gradually changes the opacity, for selected
>   elements, from hidden to visible (fading effect).

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadein.asp

Maybe [this](http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/) is more what you're looking for. The pertinent bits being the transition property. Example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rxknLLx/)

Summary of changes:

- Removed the fade in and fade out.
- Moved the light mode from html.light to html (cleaner markup, and more importantly: no undefined state of neither light nor dark)
- Added: "transition: all 0.8s;" to
  both styles

JS

```
// Check if localStorage is supported
if ('localStorage' in window && typeof localStorage == 'object') {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Set the class if greyscale is set
        // Note that localStorage saves everything as strings
        if (localStorage["darkmode"] == "1") {
            $('html').addClass('dark');
            $('.daytime').addClass('nighttime').removeClass('daytime');
            $("#lightson").val("Turn Lights back on");
        }
        // Register click listener for the button
        $('#lightson').click(function () {
            // Toggle greyscale on and off
            if (localStorage["darkmode"] != "1") {
                $('html').addClass('dark');
                localStorage["darkmode"] = "1";
                $('.daytime').addClass('nighttime').removeClass('daytime');
                $("#lightson").val("Turn Lights back on");
            } else {
                $('html').removeClass('dark');
                localStorage["darkmode"] = "0";
                $('.nighttime').addClass('daytime').removeClass('nighttime');
                $("#lightson").val("Dark Mode");
            }
        }); // - button click
    }); // - doc ready
}
```

CSS

```
html {
    background:white;
    color:grey;
    transition: all 0.8s;
}
html.dark {
    background: grey;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.8s;
}
```

Comment: He might have misunderstood the concept of "fading" but a better answer would be what the effect is called ("transition") and how he can achieve the effect he desires.

Comment: The "A simple fade with CSS3" link was meant to show him how to achieve his goal. I'll elaborate.

Comment: Thanks Anananasu, I appreciate your response very much. Aaron is right in that I didn't quite describe probably what I was after. It is more of a transition and not a fade. The CSS is not quite the right solution as it has a fade in a effect every time the page loads.

Thanks for cleaning up and removing the html.light class. Thats much better.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a CSS3 `transition` instead of JS animations:

```
html{
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v5vw9r3a/4/

---

However, to answer your asked question, `fadeOut` the element, and make the class change and `fadeIn` a callback of it, i.e.:

```
$html = $('html'); // Don't search for the element so many times -- that is slow
$html.fadeOut("fast",function(){ // fadeOut fast, then:
    $html.addClass('dark').removeClass('light').fadeIn("fast"); // addClass, removeClass, and fadeIn
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v5vw9r3a/5/

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to limit the transition to what the OP wants ? Namely the opacity and color ?

Comment: @AntoineCombes You could use `transition: background 0.5s, color 0.5s`, but since they are the only two properties being transitioned, `all 0.5s` is simply shorter.

Comment: I understand that. I wanted to know if, from some performance point of view, there was a difference.

Comment: Thank you kindly. The problem with the transition css is that it happens everytime the page is loaded. And thank you too for the second solution however it seems to not load the css background color smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

You need jQuery ui to make transitions between classes.

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/v5vw9r3a/6/

```
$('html').addClass('dark', 1000, "easeOutSine");
```

Comment: At first glance, this is exactly what I was after, thanks so much Bojan! I need to go through all the wonderful answers thoroughly tomorrow. Thanks everybody.